Initializing a map container only if it is not already initialized in Leaflet
I have a very specific "Map container is already initialized" problem different from other such questions I've found in my prior search. My web page has a lot of images. If the images have a location associated with them, they are rendered as a simple carousel. Clicking on the carousel renders and reveals their specifc map location. In other words, there are several maps on the web page.
The problem is such -- if the user clicks on an image to reveal its map, then clicks back to view the image, and then clicks to see the map again, the following error is triggered:

"Map container is already initialized"

Below is the simplified code that reproduces the problem:
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-control">
        <a href="#slide-1-000487" class="slider-link image"></a>
        <a href="#slide-2-000487" class="slider-link map" 
            data-latitude="20.613056" 
            data-longitude="92.32667" 
            data-id="000487"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slides">
        <div id="slide-1-000487">
            <img src="path/to/img/000487">
        </div>
        <div id="slide-2-000487">
            <div id="slide-map-000487" class="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-control">
        <a href="#slide-1-000555" class="slider-link image"></a>
        <a href="#slide-2-000555" class="slider-link map" 
            data-latitude="51.505" 
            data-longitude="-0.09" 
            data-id="000555"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slides">
        <div id="slide-1-000555">
            <img src="path/to/img/000555">
        </div>
        <div id="slide-2-000555">
            <div id="slide-map-000555" class="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function drawMap(event) {
        const tgt = event.currentTarget;
        const latitude = tgt.dataset.latitude;
        const longitude = tgt.dataset.longitude;
        const mapContainerId = `slide-map-${tgt.dataset.id}`;
        
        const map = L.map(mapContainerId).setView([latitude, longitude], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(map);
        const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);  
    }

    const maps = document.querySelectorAll("a.map");
    maps.forEach(m => {
        m.addEventListener('click', drawMap)
    });
</script>

Understandably, I don't want to keep track of the map containers in a global variable. I was hoping for something like an L.isNotInitialized(map) function

There is no workaround here without created map objects being saved. Even if you would get container of the already created map, you are still missing map object to add marker to it.
Simple solution for this could look like this (not tested):
var maps = {};

function drawMap(event) {
  const tgt = event.currentTarget;
  const latitude = tgt.dataset.latitude;
  const longitude = tgt.dataset.longitude;
  const mapContainerId = `slide-map-${tgt.dataset.id}`;
  
  var map = maps[tgt.dataset.id];
  if (!map) {
    const map = L.map(mapContainerId);
    maps[tgt.dataset.id] = map;
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
  }
  map.setView([latitude, longitude], 13);
  const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);  
}

const maps = document.querySelectorAll("a.map");
maps.forEach(m => {
    m.addEventListener('click', drawMap)
});


See slightly modified answer regarding setView.

You can delete container map every click the button with async function and add this code
await new Promise(resolve => {
  $(".map").replaceWith(`<div class="map">`)
  setTimeout(resolve, 0)
})

